# Rhino Mocks: Expect a method call after property set

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

I have a class to test that associates with an interface:

```
interface IMyFactory
{
    int MyProperty {get; set;}
    int Create(int x);
}

class ClassToTest
{
    public IMyFactory Factory {get; set;}

    public int Calculate(int x, int y)
    {
        this.MyFactory.MyProperty = x;
        this.MyFactory.Calculate(y);
    }
}
```

I know how to verify that method `ClassToTest.Calculate(x, y)` will set MyProperty to x.
I also know how to verify that `IFactory.Calculate`is called with value y.

But how do I assert that **calculate** is called **after** MyProperty has been set?

I tried this:

```
MockRepository mockRepository = new MockRepository();
IMyFactory mockedFactory = mockRepository.StrictMock<IMyFactory>();

int x = 4;
int y = 5;
MyClass testObject = new ClassToTest
{
    Factory = mockedFactory,
};

using (mockRepository.Record())
{
     // expect that Factory.MyProperty is set once to a value of x:
     mockedFactory.Expect( (x) => x.MyProperty)
                  .SetPropertyWithArgument(x)
                  .Repeat.Once();

     // expect that Factory.Calculate is called once with a value of y
     mockedFactory.Expect( (x) => x.Calculate(Arg<int>.Is.Equal(y))
                  .Repeat.Once();
}
using (mockRepository.Playback())
{
    testObject.Calculate(x, y);
}
```

But how do I verify that **MyProperty is set to x before Calculate(y) is called**?

Comment: It seems that checking for a call of `Calculate()` method is not the main goal. The better way is checking the state of the object after calling `Calculate ()`. In this way there is no meaning who called first.

Comment: If the factory Create uses MyProperty as well as the input parameter, I need to be certain that this function has set MyProperty to value x before Factory.Create(y) is called.